# Дополнительные свойства товаров?

Tags: битрикс

Здравствуйте.

Как можно в карточку товаров добавить несколько полей для заполнения покупателями?

Например для товара необходимо, чтобы покупатель указал размер. То, что будет введено должно будет отображаться в корзине под самим товаром. На стоимость эти поля влиять никак не должны.

То же самое с галочками. Можно ли добавить в карточку товаров несколько опций, чтобы покупатель выбирал. На стоимость влиять галочки также не должны. Просто добавляться под товар.

Поля для заполнения и галочки для всех товаров одинаковые.

Редакция Малый бизнес, версия 15.5.10.

Спасибо за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1):

В битриксе есть торговые предложения которые используются для хранения различных исполнений товара (например цвет, размер) - получается есть 1 товар и есть несколько его предложений в разных размерах и пользователь кладёт в корзину нужное предложение таким образом можно сделать "опции".

А вот текстовые поля реализовать стандартным способом не получится, хотя и не очень понятно зачем ведь всё информацию пользователь должен указать при оформлении товара. Можно конечно сохранять значения введённые в поля в куку и показывать на странице корзины и при оформлении заказа всю эту информацию записывать в поле комментарий.

Так же можно добавлять введённое значение в вариант свойства типа список и генерировать для него торговое предложение и класть в корзину уже это торговое предложение, но это так себе решение.

Comment: Торговые предложения в данном случае не подходят, т.к. все поля и галочки для товаров в нашем случае одинаковые. Товаров около 1000, совершенно неразумно из-за нескольких одинаковых полей и галочек тратить столько времени. Да и к тому же, если в будущем понадобится добавить какое-то новое поле – снова вручную править все товары и их предложения.

Comment: Отдаленно похоже на то, что нам нужно можно сделать через Свойство, добавляемое в корзину. Добавить в инфоблок Свойство, сделать его обязательным и в настройках вывода каталога добавить это свойство в пункте Добавление в корзину. Но здесь два нюанса. Во-первых, почему-то не работает добавление свойства типа Строка. Радиокнопки работают, список работает, строка – нет. Во-вторых, выбор дополнительных свойств показывается в окне после нажатия на кнопку Купить. Нужно, чтобы отметить можно было на карточке товара перед Купить.

Comment: Ну тогда только геморой через куки

Answer (score 0):

Не какого гемороя тут нет и куки не нужны.
Вам нужно на кнопку добавления товара в корзину написать свою функцию закладки товара, которая будет еще и нужные Вам свойства прикреплять к товару в корзине.
Все это очень просто. например:

```
Add2BasketByProductID(
            $PRODUCT_ID,
            2,
            array(
                    array("NAME" => "Цвет", "CODE" => "CLR", "VALUE" => "красный"),
                    array("NAME" => "Размер", "VALUE" => "25")
                )
        );
```

возможно также придется подправить саму карточку товара (шаблон компонента), чтобы вывести нужные Вам поля.